# Помогите переделать функцию поворота под Vector3

Tags: c#, геометрия

Есть у меня функция на C#:

```
public static Vector2 RotateBy(Vector2 v, float a)
{
    a = -a;
    var ca = System.Math.Cos(a);
    var sa = System.Math.Sin(a);
    var rx = v.x * ca - v.y * sa;

    return new Vector2((float)rx, (float)(v.x * sa + v.y * ca));
}
```

Кто хорошо знает математику, можете подсказать как сделать это для 3d пространства(сейчас она для координат x, z. Как добавить в эту формулу еще y) ?
То есть для Vector3.
Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: а что такое поворот в 3d пространстве? Обычно используют сферические координаты на 2 углах. cos(a)*cos(b) cos(a)*sin(b) sin(a)

Comment: Формула var a = v.x * ca - v.y * sa; Для 2 координат (x, z).
Как сделать еще под y эту формулу ?
Я 2 дня искал реализацию этой функции так как в математике очень плохо понимаю...
А нашел только для 2d мира (это для игры функция.)

Answer (score 0):

Вращение в трёхмерном пространстве бывает только вокруг какой-то оси.

Поэтому нужно нечто подобное:

```
public class RotationMatrix
{
    readonly double[,] m = new double[3, 3];

    public RotationMatrix(UnitVector3 axis, double angle)
    {
        double sin = Math.Sin(angle), cos = Math.Cos(angle);
        double onemcos = 1 - cos;

        double ux = axis.X, uy = axis.Y, uz = axis.Z;

        m[0, 0] = cos + ux * ux * onemcos;
        m[0, 1] = ux * uy * onemcos - uz * sin;
        m[0, 2] = ux * uz * onemcos + uy * sin;

        m[1, 0] = uy * ux * onemcos + uz * sin;
        m[1, 1] = cos + uy * uy * onemcos;
        m[1, 2] = uy * uz * onemcos - ux * sin;

        m[2, 0] = uz * ux * onemcos - uy * sin;
        m[2, 1] = uz * uy * onemcos + ux * sin;
        m[2, 2] = cos + uz * uz * onemcos;
    }

    public Vector3 Rotate(Vector3 original)
    {
        return new Vector3(
            m[0, 0] * original.X + m[0, 1] * original.Y + m[0, 2] * original.Z,
            m[1, 0] * original.X + m[1, 1] * original.Y + m[1, 2] * original.Z,
            m[2, 0] * original.X + m[2, 1] * original.Y + m[2, 2] * original.Z);
    }

    // остальные методы скипнул
}
```

`UnitVector3` должен быть единичным вектором.

Пользоваться так:

```
new RotationMatrix(axis, angle).Rotate(v)
```

Comment: Ну я не очень понял... А как повернуть тогда по 3-м осям ?
Поворот же может быть не только по 1 оси.
Для этого я и спрашивал как добавить еще y координату.
Ну забыл упомянуть про то что как бы еще поворачивать по всем осям.

Comment: @FreeTV: Нет понятия «повернуть по трём осям». Любой поворот есть поворот вокруг какой-либо оси (доказательство в любом курсе аналитической геометрии). Если вам нужна _композиция_ поворотов относительно любых (трёх или любого количества) осей, просто перемножьте матрицы.

Comment: Оказалось то что мне нужно делается через тригонометрию (sin, tg, cos)